# How can I view different positions of my form?

Tags: c#, forms, size, windows-forms-designer

My question is how can I view different parts of my form. Let for example make a form with these properties:
size : 280 ; 280

Now let's say we split it in 4 boxes, left top , right top , left bottom , right bottom.
(so every box is 140 ; 140 big , but their respective postion is different)

Now I want to make my user have 3 choices in the left top 'box' we just made and I want the form to be just as big as this box. Once my user clicks a button, he goes to 1 of the other 'boxes' and also only showing that one box specifically. and also being as big as this box.
so actually changing the position of my form.

If this is not possible within forms then I'll just make 1 different form and I'll do a case to check what button is clicked and it will create that specific form.

EDIT: I might not have said that I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and the WindowsFormsApplication. So it's C# indeed

Comment: yeah sorry I miscalculated , thanks though ;)

Comment: If I had some incorrect spelling, then I'm sorry. I'm from Belgium and English is not my mother language.

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly the movable viewport that you describe, you could achieve the same effect by moving `Panel` controls around as in this code.  In the Windows Forms designer, you have your 280, 280 form, and in each quadrant of that form you have a 140, 140 `Panel` control in which you place each quadrant's controls.  For the code below, `panel1` is at Location 0, 0 and contains the three buttons.  `panel2` is at 140, 0, `panel3` is at 0, 140, and `panel4` is at 140, 140.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Size = new Size(140, 140);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveFormToPanel(panel2);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveFormToPanel(panel3);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveFormToPanel(panel4);
    }

    private void moveFormToPanel(Panel panel)
    {
        this.Location = this.Location + new Size(panel.Location.X, panel.Location.Y);
        this.panel1.Visible = false;
        panel.Location = this.panel1.Location;
        panel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but not really how I want it.If we are going to use this example: I really want both(4) my panels to stay on their different locations. Not just moving the panel to the top-left and hiding the back one. Really go to the panel position. Or if this is not possible temporarly switch the positions maybe?

Comment: I don’t know how to treat the form as a viewport.  To my knowledge, when the form moves, so does everything within.  Hopefully someone can provide a better answer.